# "ı,ü,ğ,ş,ç,o" Turkish character casting on Android

Tags: android, listview, character

I have search area(edittext) and a list of bus stops. When a character is entered, the list is filtered simultaneously.

There are bus stops including Turkish characters like "beşiktaş". I want the list to show me "beşiktaş" when I entered "besiktas".

I have all data (many turkish charactered data) on server database and there are approximately 5500 bus stops. So I can't do casting on mobile devices because of insufficient RAM.

Comment: What is your database and how are you doing the filtering?  Please show your server code.

Comment: when the application starts all bus stops are got into the static arraylist.The arraylist type is "Station" which has id(int), name(String), lat(Double) and lon(Double). the code checks each item's name and filter the list.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following: (1) where your data is coming from; (2) your database structure; (3) your existing code to find a match.  After that we'll have a better chance at helping you.  So far there's just not enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the very limited information you provided, here's what you can do (this is not the fastest way but it should work for you):

1) In your `Station` class, add following fields:

```
private String latinName;
private static Map<String, String> tokens;
private static Pattern patter;
```

2) Add the following static initialiser to your `Station` class:

```
static {
    tokens = new HashMap<String,String>();

    tokens.put("\u00C0", "A");
    tokens.put("\u00C1", "A");
    tokens.put("\u00C2", "A");
    tokens.put("\u00C3", "A");
    tokens.put("\u00C4", "A");
    tokens.put("\u00C5", "A");
    tokens.put("\u00C6", "AE");
    tokens.put("\u00C7", "C");
    tokens.put("\u00C8", "E");
    tokens.put("\u00C9", "E");
    tokens.put("\u00CA", "E");
    tokens.put("\u00CB", "E");
    tokens.put("\u00CC", "I");
    tokens.put("\u00CD", "I");
    tokens.put("\u00CE", "I");
    tokens.put("\u00CF", "I");
    tokens.put("\u00D0", "D");
    tokens.put("\u00D1", "N");
    tokens.put("\u00D2", "O");
    tokens.put("\u00D3", "O");
    tokens.put("\u00D4", "O");
    tokens.put("\u00D5", "O");
    tokens.put("\u00D6", "O");
    tokens.put("\u00D8", "O");
    tokens.put("\u00D9", "U");
    tokens.put("\u00DA", "U");
    tokens.put("\u00DB", "U");
    tokens.put("\u00DC", "U");
    tokens.put("\u00DD", "Y");
    tokens.put("\u00DF", "s");
    tokens.put("\u00E0", "a");
    tokens.put("\u00E1", "a");
    tokens.put("\u00E2", "a");
    tokens.put("\u00E3", "a");
    tokens.put("\u00E4", "a");
    tokens.put("\u00E5", "a");
    tokens.put("\u00E6", "ae");
    tokens.put("\u00E7", "c");
    tokens.put("\u00E8", "e");
    tokens.put("\u00E9", "e");
    tokens.put("\u00EA", "e");
    tokens.put("\u00EB", "e");
    tokens.put("\u00EC", "i");
    tokens.put("\u00ED", "i");
    tokens.put("\u00EE", "i");
    tokens.put("\u00EF", "i");
    tokens.put("\u00F1", "n");
    tokens.put("\u00F2", "o");
    tokens.put("\u00F3", "o");
    tokens.put("\u00F4", "o");
    tokens.put("\u00F5", "o");
    tokens.put("\u00F6", "o");
    tokens.put("\u00F8", "o");
    tokens.put("\u00F9", "u");
    tokens.put("\u00FA", "u");
    tokens.put("\u00FB", "u");
    tokens.put("\u00FC", "u");
    tokens.put("\u00FD", "y");
    tokens.put("\u00FF", "y");
    tokens.put("\u0100", "A");
    tokens.put("\u0101", "a");
    tokens.put("\u0102", "A");
    tokens.put("\u0103", "a");
    tokens.put("\u0104", "A");
    tokens.put("\u0105", "a");
    tokens.put("\u0106", "C");
    tokens.put("\u0107", "c");
    tokens.put("\u0108", "C");
    tokens.put("\u0109", "c");
    tokens.put("\u010A", "C");
    tokens.put("\u010B", "c");
    tokens.put("\u010C", "C");
    tokens.put("\u010D", "c");
    tokens.put("\u010E", "D");
    tokens.put("\u010F", "d");
    tokens.put("\u0110", "D");
    tokens.put("\u0111", "d");
    tokens.put("\u0112", "E");
    tokens.put("\u0113", "e");
    tokens.put("\u0114", "E");
    tokens.put("\u0115", "e");
    tokens.put("\u0116", "E");
    tokens.put("\u0117", "e");
    tokens.put("\u0118", "E");
    tokens.put("\u0119", "e");
    tokens.put("\u011A", "E");
    tokens.put("\u011B", "e");
    tokens.put("\u011C", "G");
    tokens.put("\u011D", "g");
    tokens.put("\u011E", "G");
    tokens.put("\u011F", "g");
    tokens.put("\u0120", "G");
    tokens.put("\u0121", "g");
    tokens.put("\u0122", "G");
    tokens.put("\u0123", "g");
    tokens.put("\u0124", "H");
    tokens.put("\u0125", "h");
    tokens.put("\u0126", "H");
    tokens.put("\u0127", "h");
    tokens.put("\u0128", "I");
    tokens.put("\u0129", "i");
    tokens.put("\u012A", "I");
    tokens.put("\u012B", "i");
    tokens.put("\u012C", "I");
    tokens.put("\u012D", "i");
    tokens.put("\u012E", "I");
    tokens.put("\u012F", "i");
    tokens.put("\u0130", "I");
    tokens.put("\u0131", "i");
    tokens.put("\u0132", "IJ");
    tokens.put("\u0133", "ij");
    tokens.put("\u0134", "J");
    tokens.put("\u0135", "j");
    tokens.put("\u0136", "K");
    tokens.put("\u0137", "k");
    tokens.put("\u0139", "L");
    tokens.put("\u013A", "l");
    tokens.put("\u013B", "L");
    tokens.put("\u013C", "l");
    tokens.put("\u013D", "L");
    tokens.put("\u013E", "l");
    tokens.put("\u013F", "L");
    tokens.put("\u0140", "l");
    tokens.put("\u0141", "l");
    tokens.put("\u0142", "l");
    tokens.put("\u0143", "N");
    tokens.put("\u0144", "n");
    tokens.put("\u0145", "N");
    tokens.put("\u0146", "n");
    tokens.put("\u0147", "N");
    tokens.put("\u0148", "n");
    tokens.put("\u0149", "n");
    tokens.put("\u014C", "O");
    tokens.put("\u014D", "o");
    tokens.put("\u014E", "O");
    tokens.put("\u014F", "o");
    tokens.put("\u0150", "O");
    tokens.put("\u0151", "o");
    tokens.put("\u0152", "OE");
    tokens.put("\u0153", "oe");
    tokens.put("\u0154", "R");
    tokens.put("\u0155", "r");
    tokens.put("\u0156", "R");
    tokens.put("\u0157", "r");
    tokens.put("\u0158", "R");
    tokens.put("\u0159", "r");
    tokens.put("\u015A", "S");
    tokens.put("\u015B", "s");
    tokens.put("\u015C", "S");
    tokens.put("\u015D", "s");
    tokens.put("\u015E", "S");
    tokens.put("\u015F", "s");
    tokens.put("\u0160", "S");
    tokens.put("\u0161", "s");
    tokens.put("\u0162", "T");
    tokens.put("\u0163", "t");
    tokens.put("\u0164", "T");
    tokens.put("\u0165", "t");
    tokens.put("\u0166", "T");
    tokens.put("\u0167", "t");
    tokens.put("\u0168", "U");
    tokens.put("\u0169", "u");
    tokens.put("\u016A", "U");
    tokens.put("\u016B", "u");
    tokens.put("\u016C", "U");
    tokens.put("\u016D", "u");
    tokens.put("\u016E", "U");
    tokens.put("\u016F", "u");
    tokens.put("\u0170", "U");
    tokens.put("\u0171", "u");
    tokens.put("\u0172", "U");
    tokens.put("\u0173", "u");
    tokens.put("\u0174", "W");
    tokens.put("\u0175", "w");
    tokens.put("\u0176", "Y");
    tokens.put("\u0177", "y");
    tokens.put("\u0178", "Y");
    tokens.put("\u0179", "Z");
    tokens.put("\u017A", "z");
    tokens.put("\u017B", "Z");
    tokens.put("\u017C", "z");
    tokens.put("\u017D", "Z");
    tokens.put("\u017E", "z");
    tokens.put("\u017F", "s");
    tokens.put("\u0192", "f");
    tokens.put("\u01A0", "O");
    tokens.put("\u01A1", "o");
    tokens.put("\u01AF", "U");
    tokens.put("\u01B0", "u");
    tokens.put("\u01CD", "A");
    tokens.put("\u01CE", "a");
    tokens.put("\u01CF", "I");
    tokens.put("\u01D0", "i");
    tokens.put("\u01D1", "O");
    tokens.put("\u01D2", "o");
    tokens.put("\u01D3", "U");
    tokens.put("\u01D4", "u");
    tokens.put("\u01D5", "U");
    tokens.put("\u01D6", "u");
    tokens.put("\u01D7", "U");
    tokens.put("\u01D8", "u");
    tokens.put("\u01D9", "U");
    tokens.put("\u01DA", "u");
    tokens.put("\u01DB", "U");
    tokens.put("\u01DC", "u");
    tokens.put("\u01FA", "A");
    tokens.put("\u01FB", "a");
    tokens.put("\u01FC", "AE");
    tokens.put("\u01FD", "ae");
    tokens.put("\u01FE", "O");
    tokens.put("\u01FF", "o");

    String patternString = "(\u00C0|\u00C1|\u00C2|\u00C3|\u00C4|\u00C5|\u00C6|\u00C7|\u00C8|\u00C9|\u00CA|\u00CB|\u00CC|\u00CD|\u00CE|\u00CF|\u00D0|\u00D1|\u00D2|\u00D3|\u00D4|\u00D5|\u00D6|\u00D8|\u00D9|\u00DA|\u00DB|\u00DC|\u00DD|\u00DF|\u00E0|\u00E1|\u00E2|\u00E3|\u00E4|\u00E5|\u00E6|\u00E7|\u00E8|\u00E9|\u00EA|\u00EB|\u00EC|\u00ED|\u00EE|\u00EF|\u00F1|\u00F2|\u00F3|\u00F4|\u00F5|\u00F6|\u00F8|\u00F9|\u00FA|\u00FB|\u00FC|\u00FD|\u00FF|\u0100|\u0101|\u0102|\u0103|\u0104|\u0105|\u0106|\u0107|\u0108|\u0109|\u010A|\u010B|\u010C|\u010D|\u010E|\u010F|\u0110|\u0111|\u0112|\u0113|\u0114|\u0115|\u0116|\u0117|\u0118|\u0119|\u011A|\u011B|\u011C|\u011D|\u011E|\u011F|\u0120|\u0121|\u0122|\u0123|\u0124|\u0125|\u0126|\u0127|\u0128|\u0129|\u012A|\u012B|\u012C|\u012D|\u012E|\u012F|\u0130|\u0131|\u0132|\u0133|\u0134|\u0135|\u0136|\u0137|\u0139|\u013A|\u013B|\u013C|\u013D|\u013E|\u013F|\u0140|\u0141|\u0142|\u0143|\u0144|\u0145|\u0146|\u0147|\u0148|\u0149|\u014C|\u014D|\u014E|\u014F|\u0150|\u0151|\u0152|\u0153|\u0154|\u0155|\u0156|\u0157|\u0158|\u0159|\u015A|\u015B|\u015C|\u015D|\u015E|\u015F|\u0160|\u0161|\u0162|\u0163|\u0164|\u0165|\u0166|\u0167|\u0168|\u0169|\u016A|\u016B|\u016C|\u016D|\u016E|\u016F|\u0170|\u0171|\u0172|\u0173|\u0174|\u0175|\u0176|\u0177|\u0178|\u0179|\u017A|\u017B|\u017C|\u017D|\u017E|\u017F|\u0192|\u01A0|\u01A1|\u01AF|\u01B0|\u01CD|\u01CE|\u01CF|\u01D0|\u01D1|\u01D2|\u01D3|\u01D4|\u01D5|\u01D6|\u01D7|\u01D8|\u01D9|\u01DA|\u01DB|\u01DC|\u01FA|\u01FB|\u01FC|\u01FD|\u01FE|\u01FF)";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
}
```

3) Add the following function to your `Station` class:

```
public static String latinString(String string) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while(matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, tokens.get(matcher.group(1)));
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);

    return = sb.toString();
}
```

4) Make sure to have the following code in the setter for the `name` class variable in you `Station` class:

```
public void setName(String _name) {
    this.name = _name;
    this.latinName = Station.latinString(_name).toLowerCase();
}
```

Now, when you set the name of a station, a latin-character (without accents) representation version of that station's name will also be set.

5) When you need to compare user's input to station's name, instead compare `Station.latinString(userInput).toLowerCase()` to `yourStation.getLatinName()` - this way any likely matches will be caught.

Answer (score 0):

You can use char array instead of strings on your search algorithm. So you can make turkish character control. This will not be an efficient solution but I can't tell more without knowing your structure.